# How to evaluate the integral $\int_0^{\infty}[I_{(0,2)}(z)]\frac{(n-1)(y-z)^{n-2}}{y^{n-1}}dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, self-learning

I am doing a statistical calculation from a statistical exercise but get stuck at the following integral.

$$\int_0^{\infty}[I_{(0,2)}(z)] \frac{(n-1)(y-z)^{n-2}}{y^{n-1}}dy$$ $0<z<y$

$I_{(0,2)}(z)$ is an indicator function.

Comment: Looks to me to diverge by limit comparison with $\frac{1}{y}$.

Comment: I totally agree with John Brevik, the integral is clearly divergent. There is also a non-integrable singularity in the origin. Time to discuss this kind of questions on Meta.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio If you ask a question on Meta, do you provide a link here to that discussion?

Comment: @mickep: sure - http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21406/what-is-should-be-the-right-way-for-closing-nonsensical-questions

Comment: Thanks, for your comments, I modified this question. In fact, this question is  an exercise, it even has a solution, but I really don't know how to get it.

Comment: Suddenly, in your new question (your calculation in the end), it looks like you are integrating with respect to $z$. Please clarify.

Comment: Excersises with typos are the worst.

Comment: Thanks. as I say in the modified text, it is a typo in the book which cause the problem. In fact, I would like to keep the mistakes there, it will help other people when they see the same problem. If I modify the question I think it will be less valuable..

Comment: I suggest that you move the end of your post, starting with "The indicator function i just..." to an answer, and accept it. That way, this question will be completed.

Comment: @Stig Hemmer, agree, it cost a lot of time to try to find a solution. If it is $\int_0^{\infty}[I_{(0,2)}(z)] \frac{(n-1)(y-z)^{n-2}}{y^{n-4}}dy$ then the integral is solvable.

Answer (score 3):

Ok,I solved the problem, in fact, **our book** has a typo it should be $dz$,not $dy$. Thank you for all your comments.

Now the problem becomes easy.

The indicator function is just $1$ or $0$, if , $z\in (0,2) $ then the function is $1$ else is $0$. If it is $0$ integral will be $0$.

So when $z\in (0,2) $

$$\int_0^2 \frac{(n-1)(y-z)^{n-2}}{y^{n-1}}dz\\=\frac{n-1}{y^{n-1}}\int_0^{2} (y-z)^{n-2}dz\\=-\frac{(n-1)}{y^{n-1}}\int_0^2 (y-z)^{n-2}d(y-z)\\=-\frac{(n-1)}{y^{n-1}}\frac{(y-z)^{n-1}}{n-1}\mid_0^2\\=-\frac{(n-1)}{y^{n-1}}[\frac{(y-2)^{n-1}}{n-1}-\frac{(y-0)^{n-1}}{n-1}]\\=1-(\frac{y-2}{y})^{n-1}$$

Which is the solution.

When I try to solve the problem I find that the integral $$\int_0^{\infty}[I_{(0,2)}(z)] \frac{(n-1)(y-z)^{n-2}}{y^{n-3}}dy$$ is solvable just by a small modification.